# Flipkart and AmazonAPI for Product Details and current Product Offers

Tags: python-3.x, flipkart-api

I'm looking for The Flipkart and Amazon API's which can give details like Product Name, Product Details,
Product Price And Current offers applicable on product.

while looking I stumbled upon https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/index.html but I couldn't find the API Which can return me the things I was looking for.

Any Help or guidance will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I found, you need to be affiliate to flipkart in order to be able to reach an API giving details you want.

I think the following page should not be reachable by someone not logged (lots of 403 when fetching assets and I cannot found it on webarchive.org): https://affiliate.flipkart.com/api-docs/af_prod_ref.html#querysearchapi-new (found from this website: https://www.clusterdev.com/flipkart-api-demo/).

> GET /1.0/search.{format}
> Request and Response Details
>
> Header format: curl -H "Fk-Affiliate-Id:" -H "Fk-Affiliate-Token:" ""
>
> URL:
>
> JSON: https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/search.json
> XML: https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/search.xml
>
> Request Parameters:
>
> query: Search String
> resultCount: Number of results to return (maximum 10)
>
> Example
>
> JSON Sample
>
> Request
>
> https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/search.json?query=sony+mobiles&resultCount=5
>
> Response
>
> ```
> {
>    "productInfoList": [
>          {
>    "productBaseInfoV1": {
>      "productId": "MOBE7RSEA87F8G2F",
>      "title": "Sony Xperia M4 Aqua Dual"
>      ...
>    }
>    ]
> }
> ```

If you cannot be affilliated, I think you will have to scrape the page with a package like beautifullsoup. There [some posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=flipkart+product) about the same topics than yours:

- [Python - getting Flipkart product ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659981/python-getting-flipkart-product-id),
- [Flipkart Product API - How to get top selling product from the category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335713/flipkart-product-api-how-to-get-top-selling-product-from-the-category).